# GTK Recent Chooser Menu callback not working

Tags: gtk, programming, gtk3, pygtk

I am currently very puzzled why something so simple fails so hard:

This is the source code for a very very simple recent chooser menu, but it fails.

My output is this:

```
Display name: recentchoosermenu.c
File URI: file:///home/wolf/Downloads/recentchoosermenu.c
Last application: gedit
Display name: recentchoosermenu.c
...
```

for every entry, it's always the first file.

I really have no idea why.

Thanks for any help,

Wolf

EDIT: Well this is embarassing, forgot to append the link: https://gist.github.com/3483363

Sorry.

Comment: Where is the sourcecode? Best is to provide a minimal running example.

Comment: Sorry! Would be awesome if you could have a quick look at it!

Comment: I would say this is a bug somewhere (global menu perhaps?). I did some debugging and get the same results in various scenarios. I also found the PyGTK version which you probably ported to PyGI (http://learngtk.org/pygtk-tutorial/recentchoosermenu.html) and it has the same issue. Some more testing can be done by adding the menu to a `Gtk.MenuToolButton` for example to see if it really is the menuitem that messes things up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it seems that it's a bug in the global menu somewhere. When adding the `Gtk.RecentChooserMenu` to a `Gtk.MenuToolButton` or simply disabling the global menu, the problem doesn't occur.

To test, add these two lines to the very top of your code:

```
import os
os.environ['UBUNTU_MENUPROXY'] = '0'
```

Comment: Thanks for investigating this as well :)
I will probably write my own "renderer" for the menu, as I can access all the items...

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody else has problems with *generating a recent chooser menu under ubuntu", here is how I solved it for now:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/1169963/